# Find distinct subchild element for each element with xpath

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm just lost at using xsl1.0
I'm trying to get the distinct output of each 'row' when the data is split into multiple subchilds.

Provided this data source..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <row>
    <data>
      <a>
        <b>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>BM</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>FORD</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
        </b>
      </a>
      <a>
        <b>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>ALPHA</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>BRAVO</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
        </b>
      </a>
    </data>
  </row>
  <row>
    <data>
      <a>
        <b>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>CHARLIE</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>ALPHA</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
        </b>
      </a>
      <a>
        <b>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>BM</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
          <c>
            <Vehicle>
              <ManufacturerName>ALPHA</ManufacturerName>
            </Vehicle>
          </c>
        </b>
      </a>
    </data>
  </row>
</Root>
```

I want to get an output that looks like this.

```
BM, FORD, VAUXHALL, ALPHA, BRAVO,
CHARLIE, ALPHA, VAUXHALL, BM,
```

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't figure out how to select the distinct values for each row. My current results only show the values in the first row, with any repeating values in the other rows are not shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently my xsl is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>  

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="data/a/b/c/Vehicle[not(ManufacturerName=preceding::Vehicle/ManufacturerName)]"/>  
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data/a/b/c/Vehicle">
    <xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerName"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this result.

```
BM,FORD,VAUXHALL,ALPHA,BRAVO,
CHARLIE,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend you use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get distinct values, instead of the inefficient method you are using now.

To perform separate grouping for each `row`, include the `row'`s unique id in the grouping key:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="vehicle" match="Vehicle" use="concat(ManufacturerName, '|', generate-id(ancestor::row))" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:variable name="row-id" select="generate-id()" />
        <!-- unique vahicles in this row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="data/a/b/c/Vehicle[count(. | key('vehicle', concat(ManufacturerName, '|', $row-id))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerName"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that some XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT [set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function, which makes this kind of thing much simpler.

Comment: Man you're a lifesaver.

So that's what I'm doing wrong. I didn't add the row's unique id into consideration. Thanks.

Comment: You couldn't have used it with your method. You would have to use  the `preceding-sibling` axis in your expression instead of `preceding` - and that would be complicated because the nodes you want are not siblings.